# Calling an outside function from my Metal kernel function

Tags: ios, metal

I have a simple Metal file and inside my function, I want to call a time-intensive function from a C++ library I'm importing (`interface.h`).

My goal is to offload heavy work from the CPU to the GPU which happens inside of the `signBlock` function.

Is what I'm describing possible? here's a little code (that's admittedly not very useful)

```
#include <metal_stdlib>

#include "interface.h"

using namespace metal;

kernel void testFunc();
{
   // In here, can I call function `signBlock` from `interface.h`?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the code in `signBlock()` is compatible with Metal, then yes you can call it. But the Metal Shading Language is not 100% the same as C++, so it won't accept just any C++ function. (And the code actually needs to live in a .metal source file, not in some C++ library.)

Comment: Fwiw, the library function takes a char and some bytes and returns a char